# Jenkins takes too long to load job configuration page

Tags: jenkins

We use Cloudbees Jenkins OC in our organization. The performance overall is pretty good. But every time I would click on "View Configuration" for any job, Jenkins would take north of 35 seconds to fully load the page.

Using Developers Tools (in Google Chrome), I found out that the delay is happening when below call is made:

[http://JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$AdditionalCredentials/fillCredentialsIdItems](http://JENKINS_URL/job/%3CJOB_NAME%3E/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$AdditionalCredentials/fillCredentialsIdItems)

[image]

Jenkins instance has 3 saved credentials, and from what I see, Jenkins loads the password when we click in "View Configuration" option for a job, even if your job does not use those credentials (e.g., using Source Code Management option).

I am in the process of verifying that ALL 3 credentials stored in Jenkins have valid passwords (different owners).

But I wanted to find out from community here if there is anything else that I should check?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the root cause of the latency. We had many freestyle Jenkins jobs which were polling our internal SVN repository every minute (about 200 of them). Lot of these jobs were not even actively used anymore but we had jobs lying around. As a result, there were more than 150 concurrent polling threads.

When I reduced the number of jobs polling to ~40, the latency was down to half. We will be switching polling to using webhooks instead soon, and/or reduce the polling rate of the remaining jobs.